# What happened to class JNDITransactionManagerLookup that was part of Hibernate 3 API?

Tags: hibernate

The Hibernate 3.x API contains this class:
[`org.hibernate.transaction.JNDITransactionManagerLookup`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/transaction/JNDITransactionManagerLookup.html)

In Hibernate 4.x, the class disappeared. Apparently it was never marked as deprecated, it was simply removed. I can't find any migration guide that mentions it. I'm migrating someone else's code from Hibernate 3 to 4 and that class is extended in the code.

What class replaced `JNDITransactionManagerLookup`?